# Css selection dependent on different selector's condition

Tags: css, css-selectors, conditional-statements

Is it possible to define css class behaves dependent to an other css class?

For example; when

```
a:hover
```

Then I want to set

```
p {background:#fff;}
```

Is this possible with pure css?

**Edit**: Assume that no nested relation exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want all `p` to have that style when `a:hover` regardless of where they are in the DOM, then no, you can't do that. You'll need to use a script to apply the style (or some class containing that style) to the `p` elements when `a` receives a hover.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a structure like this:

```
<a><p>...</p></a>
```

then this:

```
a:hover p {background: #fff;}
```

will work. However, block elements should not be placed inside inline elements (in this case, no `<p>` inside `<a>`

if your markup is valid, and looks like this:

```
<p><a>...</a></p>
```

then you could have

```
p:hover {background: #fff;}
```

but a descendant can't affect the parent css (unless you use javascript) while the opposite is true (parent css affects descendants)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you would be limited to these restrictions with a littl creativity. if you use fixed positioning the descendant can overlap its parent. and still respond like a descendant.

Comment: Sure but you can't generalize such a situation. It's entirely dependent on the layout.

Comment: I am no expert, but even with a combination of fixed positioning, relative positioning and hidden elements you would be limited in some situations?

Answer (score 0):

If the `<p>` tag immediately follows the `<a>` tag then you could use the adjacent sibling selector e.g.

```
a:hover+p{
    background:#fff;
}
```

This is supported in IE8+